# FIle upload to Salesforce FIles using custom REST API

Tags: contentversion

I am getting an error response "system.limitexception:Json string exceeds heap size limit\n\nexternal entry point" when testing through postman, for file upload greater than 4 MB through custom Rest API (inserting into contentversion).

Any help on this please.

Comment: Please include the relevant code that you are using to help identify what the issue is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, Apex only has 6MB of heap. Because binary data has to be encoded as base64, you have an upper limit of about 4,500,000 bytes (less because of JSON encoding). You'll need to use a standard API for uploading ContentVersion data. You can read more about it in [Insert or Update Blob Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm#inserting_a_contentversion). Basically, you construct a `multipart/form-data` form post, sending the metadata as one form element, and the file itself as another.

The request looks approximately like this:

```
POST /services/data/v23.0/sobjects/ContentVersion HTTP/1.1
Host: yourinstance.salesforce.com
Authorization: Bearer 00D...session.id...
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="boundary_string"

--boundary_string
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_content";
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "ContentDocumentId" : "069D00000000so2",
    "ReasonForChange" : "Marketing materials updated",
    "PathOnClient" : "Q1 Sales Brochure.pdf"
}

--boundary_string
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="VersionData"; filename="Q1 Sales Brochure.pdf"

Binary data goes here.

--boundary_string--
```